# Smooth streaming support flash?

Tags: flash, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, smooth-streaming, azure-media-services

I using Azure Media Service with Smooth Streaming a `*.mp4 file`.I want to using Flash Player on Asp.net MVC4

Anyone suggest me, Flash player have support Smooth Streaming? If yes, please sent me code do it.

Thanks

please: i will not use Silverlight, it final option.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a complete guide how to implement Flash Player for Smooth Streaming](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/Media-Services/how-to-guides/smooth-streaming-plugin-for-open-source-media-framework/). However you must be aware that a single `.mp4 file` **is not** a `smooth streaming source`, but a `progressive download` source. Make sure you understand the difference (there plenty sources on the internet where you can read on the different formats for media streaming)

As additional resource, here is a guide how to produce a `smooth streaming` source from your `single mp4 file`: [How to: deliver streaming content](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/Media-Services/how-to-guides/media-services-dotnet/#stream-asset); [A Task preset for Windows Azure Media Packager to conver MP4 to Smooth Streaming source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh973635.aspx).

Comment: thanks you,the code in OSMF 2.0 i dont understand where is put this code: package{....}.

Comment: So, can i need it?. This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/Jc6gx/, Can you see it. I missing something?

Comment: I will not look at your code! I have provided you the resources to make it yourself. Everything else not subject to the StackOverflow format.

Answer (score 0):

Our team just released Smooth Streaming plugin for OSMF today - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36057.

Using Smooth Streaming OSMF plugin, you can add both live and on-demand Smooth Streaming playback capabilities to existing Adobe Strobe Media Playback players and also build rich media experiences for Adobe Flash Player endpoints using the same back-end infrastructure you use today to target Smooth Streaming playback to other devices like Win8 store apps, browser, Xbox, Windows Phone, Set-top boxes, other mobile devices and so on.

Cheers,
Vishal,
Azure Media Services Team

Comment: Thanks @Vishal Sood, I tried OSMF, I tried put crosssdmain.xml and MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-v1.0.3-osmf2.0.swf on root folder Web.And http://osmf.org/dev/2.0gm/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf. 

But i just get a error: "we are unable to connect to the content you've requested. we apologize for the inconvenience". I really dont know the reason. Hope you help me